# Running bash code in python

Tags: python, bash

For one functionality, I need bash commands (12 lines of bash code). How can I put these 12 lines in between my Python code? At the moment I was using:

```
import subprocess
command = 'bash 1-line code'
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

This worked but I was only using one line of code, now I have 12 and the '' seems not to work well...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you put the lines in a shell script and call that from python?

Comment: If you're trying to run 12 distinct bash commands inside a Python script, IMO you need to rethink your program. @jedwards' suggestion of putting the bash component in a separate file and executing that via Python could work, or you could see if you can use bash exclusively for your solution

Comment: Why do you need `bash`?  It can't do anything that `python` can't do.  Write it all in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extend what you were doing. Put all your bash codes in a file named, say `script.sh` and call it using python. You can call it as you were calling normal commands, i.e using `subprocess` module:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['./script.sh'])
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked without the ".sh"! The file doesn't have the extension in my folder.

Comment: Have you used `#! /bin/bash` at the top of the file?

Comment: Yes I did. I just wanted to document that in case someone comes to this post. Code works perfectly fine anyways.

Comment: That's not just documentation... It tell which interpreter to use... Shebang operator